# XMLHttpRequest fails basic authentication

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Any idea why `XMLHttpRequest` with correct credentials in [`Pebble JS Framework`](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/guides/javascript-guide.html) fails basic authentication on Android but works in iOS?

Exactly the same code, along the lines of:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(method, url, true, user, pass);
req.send(data);
req.onreadystatechange = function() { ... }
```

Returns 401 in from Android Pebble app, but authenticates correctly in iOS.

Comment: Downvoters unite :) or at least 'splain yourselves.  Is it "what havr you tried" ? Or "show your effort/code"? I will gladly listen.

Comment: @JakeGould unfortunately it doesn't apply to me.  JS part of Pebble app work correctly on iOS already.  And always fails in Android Pebble JS framework - even with correct credentials

Comment: @JakeGould this code runs not inside of WebView I don't think it applies either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a workaround that worked for me on Android.

Don’t know why but direct authenticated request:

```
    req.open(method, fullurl, true, user, pass);
    req.send(data);
```

didn’t work for me – it always returned 401. So Instead I tried to set basic authentication via header:

```
    req.open(method, fullurl, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode(user + ":" + pass)); 
    req.send(data);
```

(where Base64 is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246813/961695) – and it worked! Perhaps there’s a bug in XmlHttpRequest implementation on android.

Comment: Why not try btoa? is javascript pure.. ¬.¬ a try `req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass));`

Comment: btoa is ASCII only

Answer (score 0):

If the request is authenticated via cookie/headers, we can set headers and make that request [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) value as false.

**withCredentials** attribute must to false in IOS otherwise, you may be getting 401 responses from the server.

Note:- In Android and web platforms works without '**withCredentials**' property also

```
 req.open(method, fullurl, true);
 req.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "CookieInfo")); 
 req.send(data);    
 request.withCredentials = false;
```